# String variable which is initialized with String Literal Pool

Tags: java, string, memory

`String s1 = "foo";`

I heard that String Literal Pool is an area of a heap.
From that statement, I thought that a String variable must have a reference to the actual value.

I tried to inspect this variable using eclipse debugger, however, I cannot see anything but `"foo"` itself.

What is inside of `s1`?
Is it a reference(address)?
How could I see it?

Comment: it´s the value of a reference, just like in any other `Object`.

Comment: I tried to print out the value, but I failed since toString() is already been overwritten.

Comment: You can't print the "value" of a reference, the way you can print the integer value of a pointer in C. Java very deliberately is hiding the internals of how a reference is stored. The JVM is allowed to use whatever value it deems appropriate.

Comment: It is just a reference(address) to a String object in the pool.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: If it is an object, `toString()` prints out something like an address. I wonder if this is not the case in `String`.

Comment: The standard is to print the hashcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string pool is implemented as a fixed capacity chained hash table with each bucket containing a list of strings with the same hash code. 
It's implementation is hidden from you by design. You can force JVM to pool string by using .intern(). In java < 7 string pool was in permgen, and can cause you a OOM if you are not careful. In 7 it was moved into heap, so possibility of OOM is much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

> String s1 = "foo";
>
> I heard that String Literal Pool is an area of a heap. From that
>   statement, I thought that a String variable must have a reference to
>   the actual value.
>
> I tried to inspect this variable using eclipse debugger, however, I
>   cannot see anything but "foo" itself.

Yes, if you try to print the value of s1 it will show you "foo" itself, as toString() method is overridden by the String class, to show the actual String which has been stored.

> What is inside of s1?
>   s1 contains the reference to the String "foo" object, which is present in String Constant Pool.
>
> Is it a reference(address)?

Yes, it is a reference(address)

> How could I see it?

You can not see the reference as Java hides it from the programmer, but on the other hand if you want to compare the reference points to same object or not, you can use hashCode() method. Just do s1.hashCode() and print it.

If you want to know more about Java String management, read out this:https://www.talentcookie.com/2016/02/java-string-whats-different/